# Need to put a min-height on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a page in three sections:

1. A header of fixed height
2. A main section that is liquid
3. A footer of fixed height

I want the page to have a minimum height so that the bottom of the footer is flush with the bottom of the window.  I want the main section in the middle to stretch, even when the contents of the main section are too short.

I know I could probably do this with JavaScript but I'd prefer to use a CSS solution if there is one.

I've tried various versions of the following code, but the main section is only expanding as far as its contents will push it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<style>
    body, header, main, footer {
        width:100%; 
        display:block;
    }
    body{
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%; 
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    header{
        background-color:#ccc;
        height:100px;
    }
    footer{
        height:100px;
        background-color:#ccc;
    }
    main {
        border:1px solid #f00;
    }
    #wrapper{
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            Header
        </header>
        <main>
            Main
        </main>
        <footer>
            Footer
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe something like this would work. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bd6swdpL/)

```
<div class="container-main">
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class='one '>one</div>
        <div class='two '>two</div>
        <div class='three '>three</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
color:#fff;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
}
.container-main {
display:table;
width:100%;
height:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
background:#efefef;
padding:4px;
border:1px solid red;
}
.wrapper {
display:table-row;
height:100%;
}
.container-fluid {
display:table-cell;
padding:10px;
background:#e1e1e3;
border:1px solid blue;
}
.one {
background:#888;
}
.two {
background:#666;
}
.three {
background:#555;
}
.one, .two, .three {
height:80px;
}
.footer {
background:#000;
display:table-row;
}
.header {
background:#000;
display:table-row;
}
```

Comment: The padding is to demonstrate the different divs but this should do the trick hopefully